# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL date as first column returns '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for first row

Tags: mysql

when using LOAD DATA LOCAL and having a date in the first column then it always stores '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for only the very first row.

When placing a string column as very first column instead everything works fine.
See cases A and B:

A)
this first two rows in csv:

```
2022-01-31,hello_world
2022-01-31,hello_stackover
```

lead to this data in the mysql table:

```
0000-00-00 00:00;00,hello_world
2022-01-31 00:00:00,hello_stackover
```

B)
this first two rows in csv:

```
hello_world,2022-01-31
hello_stackover,2022-01-31
```

lead to this data in the mysql table:

```
hello_world,2022-01-31 00:00:00
hello_stackover,2022-01-31 00:00:00
```

This is my sql:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE mydatabase.`mytable`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(my_date, any_string_column);
```

Any idea why 0000-00-00 00:00:00 only happens for the very first row and only when it is the very first column? Thanks.

Edit:
8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

Comment: I suspect there's an invisible character at the beginning of the file, most likely a BOM.

Comment: i thought of that too and deleted the whole first line. now it happens to new first line too (which was previuosly the second line and without any problem)

Comment: Your editor is probably inserting this when it saves the file. So it put it before the new first line. Check the file with a hex editor and you'll see it.

Comment: you are right, there was something. after changing to UTF-8 without bom it does not happen again. I thought notepad++ is showing all symbols (like is does for CR/LF). If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is saving the file with a BOM (Byte Order Mark) character at the beginning, which MySQL doesn't recognize. You need to disable this setting.